# Passing an array of strings from c++ to Fortran90

Tags: c++, arrays, char, arguments, fortran

I would like to be able to pass an array of strings from c++ to fortran90. I am able to pass double arrays and character arrays with the following fortran module:

```
MODULE rocker

    CONTAINS

    SUBROUTINE alltwice(numbers, doubles, n)
        INTEGER*4, INTENT(IN) :: n
        REAL(KIND=dp), INTENT(IN) :: numbers(1:n)
        REAL(KIND=dp), INTENT(OUT) :: doubles(1:n)
        DO i=1,n
            WRITE(*,*) numbers(i)
        END DO
        WRITE(*,*)
        DO i=1,n
            doubles(i)=2.0*numbers(i)
        END DO
    END SUBROUTINE alltwice

    SUBROUTINE printstring(str, k)
        CHARACTER(len=k), INTENT(IN) :: str
        WRITE(*,*) str
    END SUBROUTINE printstring

    SUBROUTINE printsevstrings(strs, ks, n)
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n, ks
        CHARACTER(len=ks), INTENT(IN) :: strs(1:n)
        WRITE(*,*)  (strs(i), i=1, n)
    END SUBROUTINE printsevstrings

END MODULE rocker
```

In the c++ code I have

```
extern "C"{
    extern void __rocker_MOD_alltwice(double a1[], double a2[], const int& n);
    extern void __rocker_MOD_printstring(const char* c, int& length);
    extern void __rocker_MOD_printsevstrings(const char* argv[], int& length, int& number);
}
```

Now I can pass double arrays using e.g.

```
const int n=4;
double a1[n], a2[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) a1[i]=i+0.5;
__rocker_MOD_alltwice(a1, a2, n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {cout << i << " " << a2[i] << endl;}
```

and character arrays using e.g.

```
string s="jkljkloi9";
const char* c=s.c_str();
int length=s.length();
__rocker_MOD_printstring(c, length);
```

but I haven't been able to make something like this work:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])  {
    length=100;
    const char* passarg[argc];
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++) passarg[i]=argv[i];
    __rocker_MOD_printsevstrings(passarg, length, argc);
}
```

Comment: Must you use only the 1990 revision of the Fortran language?  There have been three revisions since that time.  Sometimes when people say "Fortran 90", they just mean free form Fortran source (introduced in the 1990 revision) but they don't actually need to limit themselves to language features available in that specific revision.  Fortran 2003 introduced features into the language to allow portable C (and hence aspects of C++)/Fortran interoperability.  These features are widely supported on actively maintained Fortran compilers.

Comment: Huh! I didn't know this, I'll see what my options are

Comment: Look into `iso_c_binding`